# Deleting an item from a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

in a project i'm doing for school, I need to have a list of items (each item is added by the user pressing a button and such).
Each item will hold several objects/views, one of them being a button.
The button is supposed to delete the entire item (list row) created.

the code I wrote is useless, cause i made too many changes after searching google for 4 hours.

I know how to create a listView using my custom arrayadapter, how to add items to the list and how to customize the list's items (custom view). I can not figure out how to make that button delete the item it is in.

Comment: You still should provide some code, or at least better explain what seems to be the problem.

Comment: A general code is in my answer but if you post your relevant code we might help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the item, following line of code is needed

```
arrayAdapter.remove(objectListAdapterMadeFrom.get(indexOfItemToBeDeleted));
```

Also call

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

if somewhere you are using `setNotifyOnChange(false);`

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not required. The `ArrayAdapter` will automatically do it for you in it's `remove()` method.

Comment: Oh... I was not sure. I shall edit my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, thanks for your answers.

what i eventually did was this:

added "int pos;" in main activity.

added a method in main activity:

`private OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            pos = position;
        }
    };`

then, inside the button i added this line:

`alarmList.remove(pos);`

that fixed it.

i still don't know how efficient is my solution, would love to hear your thoughts.

btw, although i continued my project and added some stuff, if you still wish for the code, i'll post it all here.